# Copying fields of a class into a List of dictionaries using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Apologies in advance if the question header is confusing.  I'll try to explain with an example, hopefully it would be clear.

I've a class like below :

```
class A
{
    Dictionary<string,string> myDict;
}
```

I want to create a list of classes with the above(ex: List) using some input which would be another List of the following type:

```
class input
{
   public string elem1;
   public string elem2;
   public string elem2;
   public string elem2;
}
Ex: List<input> inputList;
```

I've accomplished the same using a foreach loop like below.  I want to know, if I can accomplish the same using LINQ in a better way:

```
var result = new List<A>();

foreach (var l in inputList)
{
    var r = new A();
    r.myDict.Add("elem1",l.elem1);
    r.myDict.Add("elem1",l.elem1);
    r.myDict.Add("elem1",l.elem1);
    r.myDict.Add("elem1",l.elem1);
    result.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: *"Here is my code from head, I want it with LINQ"*.. why? It doesn't work either way...

Comment: Why Linq? what's wrong with this?

Comment: @Rahul, it's not compile-able ;)

Comment: @Sinatr It will produce compile time errors as well as it would throw exception on runtime :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
inputList
  .Select(i => new A(){myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"elem1", i.elem1},{"elem2", i.elem2},{"elem3", i.elem3},{"elem4", i.elem4}}})
  .ToList();
```

This requires that `myDict` is public field, but from your question I think it is (or the code must be inside the class).

Also, I think you have wrong field names, because they aren't unique and such code wouldn't compile, but I assumed that names should be `elem1`, `elem2`, `elem3`, `elem4`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have generic code for any class then the best way to solve this problem is to use [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) method and [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). To retrieve all public fields with its values use code below:

```
var result = inputList
    .Select(item => new A() { 
                                myDict = item
                                           .GetType() // get item's type declaration
                                           .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)) // get all public non static fileds of item's class
                                           .ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f.GetValue(item) // get dictionary with field name as the key and field value as the value
                            })
    .ToList();
```

If you need to retrieve not only public members or properties instead of fields you can use other methods of [`class Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type). You can also create more generic algorithm and retrieve only needed fields using special attribures to its fields and [`GetCustomAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes) method.

Note that the `myDict` field must be public.

Comment: thanks, but what is "r" that is passed to GetValue above ?

Comment: @vinit TY for comment  it's refactoring problem :) I updated my answer.

Comment: Given that you are doing this for a list of objects, I would suggest creating a `List<FieldInfo>` from `inputList.GetFirst().GetType()` once, and using that in the `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to do with linq,

```
input ip = new input();
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = typeof(input).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(ip).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Linq* version can be something like this (if you want a concise code):

```
List<A> result = inputList                       // For each item in inputList
  .Select(item => new A() {                      // Create A instance
     myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { // Assign myDict within A by a dictionary
       {"elem1", item.elem1},                    // Which has 4 items
       {"elem2", item.elem2},
       {"elem3", item.elem3},
       {"elem4", item.elem4}, 
     }
   })
  .ToList();                                       // Materialize as a List<A>
```

Is it more (or less) readable than the original code is an open question.